# How to use python to convert less than and more than signs to entities within a parent tag?

Tags: python, regex, entity

I'm having a hard time writing fuctioninal codes for converting `<` and `>` to `\&lt;` and `\&gt;` inside the `<sep>` parent tags. So the original codes look like this:

```
<xml>
<body>
<month>
<sep>Hello world!<p>This is 
september!</p> Hello world!<b>And today's Firday!</b></sep>
</month>
<month>
<sep><i>This is October!<i></sep>
</month>
</body>
</xml>
```

The result should be:

```
<xml>
<body>
<month>
<sep>Hello world!\&lt;p\&gt;This is 
september!\&lt;/p\&gt; Hello world!\&lt;b\&gt;And today's Firday!\&lt;/b\&gt;</sep>
</month>
<month>
<sep>\&lt;i\&gt;This is October!\&lt;i\&gt;</sep>
</month>
</body>
</xml>
```

So far, my codes are like this:

```
text1 = re.findall(r"<sep>((.|\n)*?)<\/sep>", f.read())
text2 = re.sub(r"<(.*?)>", r"\&lt;"+r"\1"+"\&gt;", text1)
```

But how do I put back the converted texts back into the original file?
Thanks!

Comment: You should provide code what have you tried. Is this a file?

Comment: can you share the code you have written so far?

Comment: I've updated the questions and added my codes. Please advice. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sample = """<xml>
<body>
<month>
<sep>Hello world!<p>This is 
september!</p> Hello world!<b>And today's Firday!</b></sep>
</month>
<month>
<sep><i>This is October!<i></sep>
</month>
</body>
</xml>"""

def encode_text(in_txt):
  out_txt = copy.copy(in_txt)
  matches = re.findall(r"<sep>((.|\n)*?)<\/sep>", in_txt)
  for (txt,_) in matches:
    out_txt = out_txt.replace(txt, re.sub(r"<(.*?)>", r"\&lt;"+r"\1"+"\&gt;", txt), 1)
  return out_txt

def decode_text(in_txt):
  out_txt = copy.copy(in_txt)
  matches = re.findall(r"<sep>((.|\n)*?)<\/sep>", in_txt)
  for (txt,_) in matches:
    out_txt = out_txt.replace(txt, re.sub(r"\\\&lt;(.*?)\\\&gt;", r"<\1>", txt), 1)
  return out_txt

result_encoded = encode_text(sample)
result_decoded = decode_text(result_encoded)
```

`print(result_encoded)` prints:

```
<xml>
<body>
<month>
<sep>Hello world!\&lt;p\&gt;This is 
september!\&lt;/p\&gt; Hello world!\&lt;b\&gt;And today's Firday!\&lt;/b\&gt;</sep>
</month>
<month>
<sep>\&lt;i\&gt;This is October!\&lt;i\&gt;</sep>
</month>
</body>
</xml>
```

while `print(result_decoded)` prints:

```
<xml>
<body>
<month>
<sep>Hello world!<p>This is 
september!</p> Hello world!<b>And today's Firday!</b></sep>
</month>
<month>
<sep><i>This is October!<i></sep>
</month>
</body>
</xml>
```

Also, note that:

```
result_decode == sample
Out[87]: True
```

Comment: Thank you very much @GPhilo! It works on the sample!! But the issue for me is I'm running this for a rather large file, like 500MB, and the regex will run more than 1h to search for `(.|\n))` I think. Is there another way to write this regex so it contains all texts including line breaks and python can digest it better?

Comment: By the way, what does the underscore mean in the `(txt,_)`, when I tried the regex `<sep>(.*?)<\/sep>` instead, I got an error message saying `too many values to unpack (expected 2)`...?

Comment: I think I found the answer. I need to wrap the regex like `<sep>((.*?))<\/sep>`. but I wouldn't mind listening to some explanations on it! :) Thank you!

Comment: Can't check at the moment as I'm travelling, but you might obtain some speedup by defining the patterns beforehand using re.compile() and then use the pattern for match, sub, findall, etc. Since you're not rebuilding the pattern every time this should be significantly faster. About the underscore, it's just a conventional name for a variable that takes a value we don't care about. The result of the function is a tuple, of which only the first value is the matched text. Check what the result is in your changed code and update the variables accordingly ;)

Comment: Thank you! Hope your trip was smooth! I tried the `copy` function, but it seems like it'd take forever to run the script. But I think the codes are perfect for smaller files! :)

Comment: Can you elaborate on the `copy` function? Which copy? And where are you using it?

Comment: Yea - I used the same copy operation you wrote `out_txt = copy.copy(in_txt)`. But since the file's 500MB (utf-16), I waited for an hour, but still no output yet, so I gave up ha.